# Syntax error near unexpected token `elif' - Already read other posts

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error, whitespace

To start, I have already looked at the previous comments in the others listed here but unfortunately, none of the help provided has solved my issue.

I am working in CentOS 7 as my environment and I am coding some error handling into my add user script.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -n "Enter username: "
read -r username
/bin/egrep -i "^${username}:" /etc/passwd
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
echo "User $username already exists. Please check the username and try again."
elif [ $? eq 1 ]
echo "User $username does not exist. Please proceed with account creation."
then
adduser "$username"
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo $username:$password | chpasswd
touch /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
echo "$username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
else
echo "Error encountered."
fi
```

When I go to test it, I get the following error message:

```
./testscript-error.sh line 7: syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'
./testscript-error.sh line 7: elif [ $? eq 1 ]
```

I've tried:

```
elif [ $? eq 1 ]**;**
echo "User $username does not exist. Please proceed with account creation."
then
adduser "$username"
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo $username:$password | chpasswd
touch /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
echo "$username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup**;**
```

I've also tried:

```
elif [ $? eq 1 ]
then
echo "User $username does not exist. Please proceed with account creation."
then
adduser "$username"
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo $username:$password | chpasswd
touch /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
echo "$username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
```

Also with the same result. Not sure what I'm missing and could use another pair of eyes on it.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Missing `then` after first `if`.

Comment: `[` is a command, but `[0` is not.  Nor is `[1`.  When you write `[$?`, you are trying to run a command named `[0` or `[1` (or whatever the value of `$?` is).  You need a space: `if [ $? ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell,

I checked the code I typed in here and added the spaces. It has the spaces on the actual box I'm running it on. I've run it through the shellchecker and can't figure out even from the help pages why it's giving me a parsing error.

Comment: @ladycoder2098 Doesn't matter. That's still the problem.

Comment: @melpomene - I feel dumb right now for missing that. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, shellcheck points out the same problem (after fixing the spaces in `[` `]`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example for a problem. (For instance, if you can replace a bunch of `adduser` / `echo` / `read` commands with just one `echo`, and still get the same problem, then your example is both shorter, *and* can be tested by people without root privileges -- reducing the effort needed to verify proposed solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... I hope you will understand better the syntax and usage:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo -n "Enter username: "
    read -r username
    /bin/egrep -i "^${username}:" /etc/passwd
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "User $username already exists. Please check the username and try again."
    else
        echo "User $username does not exist. Proceed with account creation."
        break
    fi
done

adduser "$username"
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi

echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi

touch /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
echo "$username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Aside: `if [ $? -gt 0 ]` is a much worse practice than just incorporating the `if`s into the statements whose success or failure you want to test. `if ! adduser "$username"; then ...`, or even better, a one-liner: `adduser "$username" || { echo "Error encountered" >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: ...or a one-liner with a function: `die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }`, then later: `useradd "$username" || die "Unable to add user"`

Comment: There are approximately 1 million other ways of writing such script. There is no Good or Bad as long as the job is done.

Comment: Based on the question it's clear that is a beginner who just doesn't see his mistakes and just needs an example which would simply correct his simple logic. No complex syntax will achieve that.

Comment: There are certainly measures along which to measure goodness. One of those is robustness: If code is less likely to break when modified, that's better than when it's more likely to break. (Adding new logging, for instance, can disrupt `$?`, making reliance on its values fragile). Another of those measures is repetition: Code that follows DRY -- Don't Repeat Yourself -- is easier to modify in one place (ie. in the function I gave above, you can change whether your errors are logged to stdout or stderr by making a change in only one place).

Comment: Unfamiliar syntax is only new to people who don't know it yet. If it's taught, then it's no longer complex or surprising; that's part of why we teach best practices, rather than letting folks stumble around on their own.

Comment: As for "die", it's actually [in the BashFAQ #101 library of common idiom](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/101).

Comment: ...and you can see the entry on testing `$?` explicitly in the [irc.freenode.org #bash channel's factoid database](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/%5b%24%3f), showing longstanding consensus (the leftmost column is timestamp in seconds-since-epoch) on the subject. The topic is also overlapped on by some historical versions of [the factoid on `$?` itself](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/%24%3f).

Comment: So first of all I'm female, not a guy so please watch your pronouns. Secondly, I haven't written bash before, but I understand the basics of coding so I'm not a "beginner" I'm just inexperienced in this particular language. All coding has its own nuances, bash being one of the harder ones. Thirdly, I'm changing my script a bit so that it can add a user to a group rather than create this sudoers file that I can't delete people out of without removing the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the finished working code.

```
#!/bin/bash
#========================================================================================================
# This script allows for account creation on a server                                                   |
# It also performs error handling to ensure that the user doesn't currently exist on the system.        |
# Also provides feedback from the input to verify the entries are correct.                              |
#========================================================================================================
while true; do
    echo -n "Enter username: "
    read -r username
    /bin/egrep -i "^${username}:" /etc/passwd
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "User $username already exists. Please check the username and try again."
    else
        echo "User $username does not exist. Proceed with account creation."
        break
    fi
done

adduser "$username"
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi

echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
echo "Password was succesfully set for $username."
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered. There was a problem with your entry. Please re-run the script and try again."
    exit 1
fi

usermod -a -G wheel "$username"
echo "User was succesfully added to the group wheel."
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi
echo "Successfully added $username to the system."
```